# Need multiple rows with same value IN OPERATOR

Tags: sql

Suppose, `order_id` `4646`, `4647` and `4648` are from same customer.

```
SELECT customer_id FROM orders WHERE order_id IN (4646, 4647, 4648)
```

Result:

```
customer_id
2589
2589
2589
```

Every customer has a `gcm_registration_token`.

```
SELECT gcm_registration_token FROM customer_details WHERE customer_id IN (2589, 2589, 2589)
```

Result:

```
gcm_registration_token
dyB_PhRHddU:APA91bGAbuxAIlHUmH2XYK0pWM3ON37O_mTF7g...
```

I want the second query to return 3 rows with same `gcm_registration_token`.

Expected result:

```
gcm_registration_token
dyB_PhRHddU:APA91bGAbuxAIlHUmH2XYK0pWM3ON37O_mTF7g...
dyB_PhRHddU:APA91bGAbuxAIlHUmH2XYK0pWM3ON37O_mTF7g...
dyB_PhRHddU:APA91bGAbuxAIlHUmH2XYK0pWM3ON37O_mTF7g...
```

A way around would be to fire query for each value. But, is it possible with single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**INNER JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) in following:

```
SELECT gcm_registration_token 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN customer_details d ON o.customer_id = d.customer_id
WHERE order_id IN (4646, 4647, 4648)
```

Comment: You can avoid answering if there is another answer present with same content. Don't take it in wrong way just a suggestion. Try and keep SO clean

Comment: Accepted for Syntactic Sugar :D

Answer (score 3):

Use `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT c.gcm_registration_token 
FROM orders o
JOIN customer_details c ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.order_id IN (4646, 4647, 4648)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT `gcm_registration_token`
FROM `orders` o
INNER JOIN `customer_details` c ON `o`.`customer_id` = `c`.`customer_id`
WHERE `o`.`order_id` IN (4646, 4647, 4648)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ord.customer_id as customerid , cd.gcm_registration_token from orders as ord 
left join customer_details as cd on cd.customer_id = ord.customer_id
WHERE ord.order_id IN (4646, 4647, 4648);
```

This query would mix customer detail table and order table and return all values that matches the where clause on the left table